# In sass what does the = mean

Tags: css, sass

For example in the following from sass. Is the = just a shorthand for @mixin? I can't seem to find any info for this on google

```
=multi-line-button($base-color)
  +background-clip('padding-box')
  border-width: 1px
  +border-radius(6px)
  border-style: solid
  color: white
  display: block
  margin: 0.2em auto
  padding: 12px 15px
  text-align: center
  text-decoration: none
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, this is the way to define mixins in Sass

dunno if [this article](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/04/02/dont-repeat-yourself-use-sass-modules.html) will help at all

EDIT:

The following are identical

```
@mixin red-text
  color: #ff0000

=red-text
  color: #ff0000
```

Just add `+red-text` to your selectors

Comment: any idea why the official documentation doesn't have this info? is it deprecated or something?

Comment: Not quite sure why it's not in the docs. But it's totally fine to use both techniques. The docs do state that using @mixin is the "way", but I've always used the "=" technique myself - SASS changes all the time so this might be a backward compatibility feature.....

Comment: For the sake of human readability `@mixin` and `@include` is more clear. Using `=` and `+` reminds me of reading through arcane makefile syntax :D

Answer (score 5):

"@mixin foobar" is the newer SCSS syntax (more CSS-like) and "=foobar" is the older SASS syntax (more HAML-like). I'm fairly new to SASS and started with SCSS, but both are supported (probably not in the same stylesheet) and both will continue to be supported.